# Flash Builder 4.5 - AS3 Code Formatter?

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, code-formatting

i'm new to Flash Builder.

while attempting to set my own format for my ActionScript 3.0 code, i found `Preferences > Java > Code Style > Formatter`.  i then set the braces and indent format so my code will automate like this when it's written:

[image]

i realize that ActionScript 3.0 and Java are completely different languages, but their syntax is nearly identical so i assumed that the Eclipse based Flash Builder would treat my AS3 as Java.  it's exactly what i'm looking for since it allows me to change the default code format:

```
private function defaultFormat():void
{
     //code
}
```

into my own preferred format:

```
private function myFormat():void
     {
     //code
     }
```

unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.  while writing my ActionScript 3.0 code it continues to auto format with the default setting.

how can i set my own format on my ActionScript 3.0 code?

---

**[EDIT]**  i just tried using the [Flex Formatter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/flexformatter/) Eclipse plugin, but (while it's latest version is only 0.8.6) it doesn't offer the ability to choose customized indenting of braces - plus it really seemed to slow down writing code in FB.

Comment: Grant Skinner recommends this plugin. http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2009/12/indispensable_p.html

Comment: hi mousedown,  i did try using Flex Formatter as stated in my previous edit, but it still doesn't offer the control i was looking for (specifically with brace indenting).  Flex Formatter only offers 2 options for code block formatting with braces (Java Style or Adobe Style).  it's just unfortunate that the built-in Java formatter doesn't work on AS3 code, since the two languages have nearly identical syntax.

Comment: It's a real shame. I too, am disappointed at the level of support. I have considered installing the FB4.5 plugin into Helios instead of using the default install but that looks to be far too problematic and I'm not sure if will even solve. Let me know if you find a solution please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Preferences > Flash Builder > Indentation > ActionScript
```

or

```
Preferences > Flash Builder > Editors > ActionScript Code
```

Unfortunately there's no Code Style for Flash Builder 4.5. You can use the above perferences to tweak some minor options but not the same amount of control as with Java.

Comment: FB 4.5 has `Preferences > Flash Builder > Editors > ActionScript Code > Indentation`, but there are only 3 options, none of which allow the formatting control i'm searching for.  i can only indent package contents, align parameters in function declarations or indent switch statement contents.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way you can do this now in version 4.7.

Go to `Window > Preferences > Flash Builder > File Templates >  ActionScript > ActionScriptClass`

Then using `Edit` button on right hand side edit the Template and click `Apply` button.